# How to open a pdf with iBooks in iPhone sdk?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, pdf

I need to open a pdf file which is in my local resource folder with iBooks. I did the following,

```
-(IBAction)openingPDF:(id)sender
{
    //get path to file you want to open
    NSString *fileToOpen = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Family_Assistance_Act-1" ofType:@"pdf"];

    //create NSURL to that path

    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:fileToOpen];

    //use the UIDocInteractionController API to get list of devices that support the file type

    UIDocumentInteractionController* docController = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:url];

    [docController retain];

    //present a drop down list of the apps that support the file type, click an item in the list will open that app while passing in the file.

    BOOL isValid = [docController presentOpenInMenuFromRect:CGRectZero inView:self.view animated:YES];

}
```

Now i want to close my app and open this pdf file with iBooks. How to achieve this? What else i need to add in this? Any suggestions or samples? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you mean with this: Now i want to close my app and open this pdf file with iBooks. For me it's still there after i close the app.